# Preview-Ghostscript replaces equations with triangles in Emacs in LaTeX mode

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview, ghostscript

I am using auctex in Emacs, and upon running Preview->Buffer (C-c C-p C-b), what happens is:

1. Triangles with red borders and white interiors replace every math formula
2. A white and empty Ghostscript command prompt pops up
3. Back in Emacs, the bottom line suggests "Type 'C-c C-l' to display results of compilation."
4. So I do "C-c C-l", and I see many sections like

> [6] !Preview: Snippet 7 started. <-><->  l.49 \item An observer can go
>   from $p$ to $q$  !Preview: Snippet 7 ended. (338603+152916x386477).
>   <-><->

It ends with

> Output written on _region_.dvi (35 pages, 7212 bytes). Transcript
>   written on _region_.log.
>
> TeX Output exited as expected with code 1
>
> Preview-DviPS finished at Sun Jul  3 00:47:34 Running
>   `Preview-Ghostscript' with ``"c:\Program
>   Files\gs\gs9.19\bin\gswin64.exe"
>   ^"-dOutputFile=^(_region_.prv/tmp6592tSU/pr1-^%d.png^)^" "-q"
>   "-dDELAYSAFER" "-dNOPAUSE" "-DNOPLATFONTS" "-dPrinted"
>   "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-sDEVICE=png16m"
>   "-r103.431x103.742"''

After this, if I close the white Ghostscript command prompt, then the buffer updates and says that Ghostscript exited abnormally with code 255.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem: My Ghostscript executables are located at C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin, and it happens that gs9.19 installs two executables, one called gswin64, the other called gswin64c. Initially, in my .emacs file, I had

```
(setq preview-gs-command (executable-find "gswin64"))
```

which produced the errors that I described above, whereas if I changed it to "gswin64c", then the LaTeX symbols appear correctly in the preview. I'm not sure what the difference is between gswin64 and gswin64c.

Comment: To quote [ghostscript documentation](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Install.htm) Section 4.2, "General Windows configuration", `GSWIN64C.EXE   Ghostscript as a 64-bit Windows command line program. This is usually the preferred executable.` and 
`GSWIN64.EXE   64-bit Ghostscript using its own window for commands`